# How to recursively Iterate an alphabet?

Tags: php, algorithm, iteration

I need to write a function which iterates through alphabet (a-z) like this:
(here is an example for a-c)

```
a
b
c

aa
ab
ac

ba
bb
bc

ca
cb
cc

aaa
aab
aac

... and so on. (until the word has 5 characters)
```

any idea how to do this? I guess I need some recursive function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for recursion!

```
for($char = 'a'; $char != 'aaaaaa'; $char++){
    echo $char . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: wow, this is awesome, quick and short :) thank you Gordon and Grexis.

Comment: wow is right, I'll be deleting my answer now, as it's embarrassing, lol.

Comment: This is emarrassingly easy, yes. Nice solution. I still say that you shouldn't delete nay answers that are OK and working, perhaps in some cases they are more useful or they can provide extra methods which is nice. :)

Comment: It's ok. I had an answer like axiomer's once, and then someone posted this and I felt like an idiot. It's interesting how php handles different data types.

Comment: Better to use a != rather than <= for your end state.... note that you can't decrement $char, only increment

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick recursive way to do it:

```
function loopchars($maxlvl,$lvlnow,$cstr){
$chars = array(); //put the chaaracters in here
for($i=0;$i<count($chars);$i++){
$uj=$cstr.$chars[$i];
if($lvlnow==$maxlvl){echo $uj.'<br />';}
else{loopchars($maxlvl,$lvlnow+1,$uj);}
}
}
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
loopchars($i,1,'');
}
```

Explained: if it did not reach the maximum level to write out, it calls itself again. And it adds every character in a loop. `loopchars($n,1,'');` makes $n-th level iterations therefore the loop makes every level between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need recursion for this? It could be tail recursive (which means that it could just be done iteratitively).  For e.g, here is a try in Python. You had tagged PHP, so if PHP has similar libraries you can try that or implement the corresponding functions in your code.

```
import itertools

mystr = "abcde"

for i in range(1,len(mystr)):
    for each in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(mystr,i):
        print "".join(each)
```

Comment: thanks, this works great in python, will try to export this to php.